# Smartgit - Can not pull, push and sync reposities and files

Tags: git, smartgit

I create a repository in GitHub and then in SmartGit I create repository and use my account to connect to GitHub, too. When I try to sync my local repository I get an error `myrepository has no tracked branch - syncing requires working trees being on a local branch which is tracked` (push and pull have an error too - command error). The same happens with files. Can someone show me how to fix these errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easier to *clone* the GitHub repo with SmartGit: the resulting local repo will have a branch tracking an upstream branch (most likely `master` tracking `origin/master`).

If you want to keep your current local repo, check if it has a remote referring to your GitHub repo:  `Remote -> Manage Remotes`.
If not, click `Add` and put in the details of the remote e.g. '`master`', '`https://github.com/yourLogin/yourRepo`'. (see [this thread for example](http://smartgit.3668570.n2.nabble.com/How-to-change-the-remote-repository-or-do-an-upstream-pull-td7367554.html))

The default branch is also set in `Project|Repository Settings`.

Answer (score 1):

What solved the issue for me is opening Git shell (from Tools menu) and doing standard pull + push:

```
git pull
git push
```